# The probability that no runs of k consecutive heads OR tails will occur in n coin tosses

Tags: probability, statistics, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to find the probability that no runs of k consecutive heads **or** tails will occur in n coin tosses. After doing some reading, I found [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinTossing.html) that shows that the probability that no k consecutive tails will occur in n tosses is given by $F^k_{n+2}/2^n$ where $F^k_l$ is a  Fibonacci k-step number.

Now this works if I am trying to see the probability that no k consecutive tails **or** no k consecutive heads occurs. But if I want to know the probability that no k consecutive tails **or** heads occurs, the problem becomes more complicated, because there are many coin flip combinations that include both k consecutive heads and k consecutive tails at the same time. If I could determine the number of combinations that included both k consecutive heads **and** k consecutive tails, I could then use it to find the number of combinations that have **either** k consecutive heads **or** k consecutive tails and sum all three of those to find the probability that no runs of k consecutive heads **or** tails will occur in n coin tosses.

Running this with R, I found that the number of combinations where there were both k consecutive heads **and** k consecutive heads that occurred was as follows:

| k | n | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | 8 | 26 |
| 3 | 9 | 74 |
| 3 | 10 | 194 |
| 3 | 11 | 482 |
| 3 | 12 | 1152 |

| k | n | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 | 2 |
| 4 | 9 | 8 |
| 4 | 10 | 26 |
| 4 | 11 | 76 |
| 4 | 12 | 206 |
| 4 | 13 | 530 |
| 4 | 14 | 1314 |

| k | n | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 9 | 0 |
| 5 | 10 | 2 |
| 5 | 11 | 8 |
| 5 | 12 | 26 |
| 5 | 13 | 76 |
| 5 | 14 | 208 |
| 5 | 15 | 542 |
| 5 | 16 | 1362 |

There seems to be a pattern that starts 2 later for each increased value of k, and has similar values that then stabilize with higher values of k. This seems to me to be related to a Fibonacci k-step number, but I can't see the pattern here.

My question is this. Is there a simpler way to calculate the probability that no runs of k consecutive heads **or** tails will occur in n coin tosses. And if not, is there a way to calculate the number of combinations with k consecutive heads **and** tails, following the pattern here.

Comment: I think there are two sentences where you wrote "heads" twice but meant to write "heads" once and "tails" once?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that! I have edited it to fix those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence obtained from your coin toss sequence by XORing pairs of consecutive tosses (with, say, tails represented by $0$ and heads by $1$). These XORs are all independent of each other and thus also behave like a sequence of coin tosses. A sequence has $k$ consecutive heads or $k$ consecutive tails iff the corresponding XOR sequence has $k-1$ consecutive $0$s. Thus, if $p_{nk}$ denotes the probability that there are no $k$ consecutive heads in a sequence of length $n$ and $q_{nk}$ denotes the probability that there are neither $k$ consecutive heads nor $k$ consecutive tails in a sequence of length $n$, then $q_{nk}=p_{n-1,k-1}$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you are saying. So p_{nk} is the same as F^{k}_{n+2}/2^n, which would make q_{nk} the same as F^{k-1}_{(n-1)+2}/2^n? When I calculate that out, it doesn't match up with the observed values.

Comment: @Squidswell: You forgot to substitute $n-1$ for $n$ in $2^n$. Does that make it match? If not, please give an example of where it goes wrong.

Comment: Good catch! That works perfectly for me now, thanks so much!